# how to reference itself in a component in vuejs single file component

Tags: vue.js

So here is my code:

```
 export default {
        data(){
            return {
                list: {}
            }
        },
        components: {
          listFields : ListFields
        },
        methods : {
            submitForm(data){
                let vm = this;
                console.log(vm);
                axios.post('/api/dashboard/lists/create', data)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        this.$router.push({path: 'show-list', params: {list_id: response.data.id}});
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    })
            }
        }
    }
```

the problem is that inside the method where I am calling "this.$router.push" it throws an error, because this references to the function. But the problem is that I can't reference vm, because I am exporting the component. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: use `vm.$router`, btw I don't understand why you can't reference it to `vm` and what relation it have with the exported component ?
Other option would be use arrow syntax into the axios method `.then(response => { this.$router.push(//etc) })`

Comment: I'd actually prefer to use .bind(this) to make the anonymous function aware of the context.

Comment: Are you sure `$router` is properly instantiated? If you added a `mounted` handler to your component and `console.log(this.$router)` does it return a value? If not, can we see how you create the router?

Comment: @BertEvans when I call it in created() method - it returns the correct value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback function is not aware of the outer context.

Either use .bind(this) or declare var that = this;

```
axios.post('/api/dashboard/lists/create', data)
  .then(function (response) {
    this.$router.push({path: 'show-list', params: {list_id: response.data.id}});
  }.bind(this)).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

or

```
var that = this;
axios.post('/api/dashboard/lists/create', data)
  .then(function (response) {
    that.$router.push({path: 'show-list', params: {list_id: response.data.id}});
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

Update:
Since somehow nothing seems to work you can try the following: Declare a seperate method for the callback

```
    methods : {
        submitForm(data){
            axios.post('/api/dashboard/lists/create', data)
                .then(this.onSuccess)
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        },
        onSuccess(response) {
           this.$router.push({path: 'show-list', params: {list_id: response.data.id}});
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did try this in the top of the submitForm function - but it throws an error that that.$router does not have push function.

Comment: what does your console.log return for vm.$router ?

Comment: When I bind it inside the submitform function it returns 'undefined'

Comment: and when I run it from created(){} method of component instance it returns the router instance correctly

Comment: it is that I cant bind the component to 'vm' because I am exporting the component

Comment: have you tried using .bind(this) on the method as shown in my first example?

Comment: result is the same, because it binds submitForm function - not the component instance.

Comment: As I know once the router is installed, it's attached to global object (window), so you don't have to reference context, you could use it just like `router.push` @naneri
Also check solution with arrow syntax.

Comment: @BelminBedak I don't know why, but that does not work in single file components. In created() method I can get $router via this.$router.

Comment: Have you tried to use arrow function as I commented on question @naneri

Comment: Sorry but I cannot believe it is not working using the bind(this) way - can you provide an update of your code using it?

Comment: No, I am not aware of the syntax of arrow functions :/ . Have not worked with modern JS for a while

Comment: Can you add the code where you call your submit method?

Comment: @FrankProvost I call it from child component method as this.$parent.$options.methods.submitForm(this.list)

Comment: @FrankProvost, so does it mean, that when I call the method from child component - it is not aware of the whole parent component and only of the method itself?

Comment: @FrankProvost it seems that I have called the method the wrong way  this.$parent.$options.methods.submitForm(this.list) was not aware of the components' scope. So I called it this.$parent.submitForm(this.list) directly and it worked. Thanks a lot for pointing me into the right direction!